# Spring cloud config server not decrypting value

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to user encrypt feature of spring cloud config server. I'v generated a keystore and set required config in application.properties

i'm able to user /encrypt and /decrypt endpoints to encrypt and decrypt value.

However encrypted values are not decrypted by config server before sending them to client!

```
encrypt.key-store.location=classpath:/config-server.jks
encrypt.key-store.alias=config-server-key
encrypt.key-store.password=changeit
encrypt.key-store.secret=changeit
```

In my .yml file i've

```
message: '{cipher}AgAAeBKZOOQ3aM...'
```

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

i was able to fix my issue: instead of putting confi properties in **application.properties**, i had to set them in **bootstrap.properties**.

```
encrypt.key-store.location=classpath:/config-server.jks
encrypt.key-store.alias=config-server-key
encrypt.key-store.password=changeit
encrypt.key-store.secret=changeit
```